# Will using the Meteor Client on Hypixel get me banned?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On their official website (https://meteorclient.com/), it says that it has things like CrystalAura and KillAura, which gives you a "large advantage in PVP." If I use this client on Hypixel, would I get banned?

Comment: The edit made this no longer opinion-based, but also not something Arqade can answer. "Does this violate the rules of some specific server" is no more answerable than "does this violate the law", which is already off-topic (see the tag wiki of [tag:legal])

Answer (score 4):

### This will ultimately depend on the server you play on.

All servers have different rules, so you will need to check the rules of the server you play on. However for most servers you would be banned for using meteor or other clients like it.

The main exception to this would be anarchy servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is considered cheating/"hacking" on most servers which largely involve PvP.
Most public servers will punish for using these types of modifications.
If you are unsure if Meteor Client is allowed on the server you are playing on, check the rules.

If you are playing on singleplayer mode, there is nothing wrong with using Meteor Client.